# Parsing a Salesforce JSON object with Python

Tags: python, json, salesforce

I'm new to Salesforce and Python and having a bit of trouble figuring this out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import csv
import json
import pdb

sf = Salesforce(
   username='jXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com', password='XXXXXX', security_token='security_token')

accDetails = sf.query("SELECT Name FROM Account")
#print(accDetails)


try:
    #pdb.set_trace()
    decoded = json.loads(accDetails)

    # Pretty printing of json-formatted string
    print json.dumps(decoded, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    print "JSON decoded: ", decoded['two']['list'][1]['item']

except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
    print "JSON format error"
```

it's throwing the "JSON format error" error. I'm sure it's someting simple I'm doing incorrectly, as I said I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Salesforce class from [here](https://github.com/heroku/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/api.py), it does not return JSON; it returns an already-decoded dict. There is no need to call `json.loads` on it.

Comment: I see. How could I then write 'accDetails' to a file(csv or txt) in a formatted structure? I can't find any straightforward solutions anywhere.

Comment: You can use `json.dumps`, like you are doing. You just don't need to call `json.loads` first.